# how can i use distinct INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get data from multiple table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738574/get-data-from-multiple-table)

```
SELECT PM.PMID,RFM.TITLE,RFM.NAME ,PV.RFMID FROM MMASTER 
INNER JOIN AMM ON MMASTER.MID=AMM.MID
INNER JOIN PS ON AMM.AMMID=PS.AMMID
INNER JOIN PV ON PV.VTID=PS.VTID
INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID
INNER JOIN PM ON PV.PMID==PM.PMID
INNER JOIN SM ON PS.SMID=SM.SMID
WHERE PM.PMID='2'

Table MMASTER
   MID col1
   1   abc
   2   xyx
   3   pqr

   Table AMM
   AMMID MID col1 col2
   1     1   bnb  mfk
   2     1   def  rwr
   3     2   re   wrwr

   Table PS
   UID VTID AMMID SMID col1 col2 
   1   1    1     1    rkk  jdj
   2   2    3     3    kdf  lfl
   6   2    2     4    rgr  rtr

   Table PV
   VTID PMID RFMID
   1    2   1
   2    2   3
   7    2   2

   Table RFM
   RFMID title name
   1     mr   john
   2     mr   jack
   3     mr   jim

   Table PM
   PMID col1 col2
   1   df  ere
   2   rwe rwer
   3   rwr fwr

   Table SM
   SMID MMID col1 col2
   1    1    fdf  efe
   2    1    ddf  dfdf
   3    2    df   ef
```

I get result like this after fire above query

```
 PMID title name  PV.RFMID
 2     mr.   jim  3
 2     mr.   jim  3
 2     mr.   jim  3
```

I have to use `distinct` in `inner join RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID`.

In my query `PV.RFMID` getting duplicate value when join with `RFM` and due to that title and name getting duplicate

How can I use `distinct` in this line

```
INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID = PV.RFMID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a subquery with that `INNER JOIN` and use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT MID,NAME,SEX,AGE,RFM.TITLE,RFM.NAME ,PV.RFMID
FROM MMASTER 
INNER JOIN AMM ON MMASTER.MID=AMM.MID
INNER JOIN PS ON AMM.AMMID=PS.AMMID
INNER JOIN PV ON PV.VTID=PS.VTID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RFMID, NAME
    FROM RFM 
) RFM 
    ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID
INNER JOIN PM ON PV.PMID==PM.PMID
INNER JOIN SM ON PS.SMID=SM.SMID
WHERE PM.PMID='13'
```

Comment: ,RFM.TITLE,RFM.NAME yet repeating

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: @John if you remove the other inner joins and just leave the two tables you provided data for are you still getting duplicates?  I am guessing the duplicate might be coming from another table.

Comment: bluefeet i want data also from those table.only PV.RFMID are repeated all data are correct,I have join seven tables

Comment: I am not saying to remove the other tables, I know that you need them.  But sometimes to debug a query it is helpful to start with a smaller query and then add other tables.  Can you add data for each table included?  It would be helpful to see some of the other data

Comment: i have add data of other table aslo

Comment: @John: A quick look reveals that a join on `PV.VTID=PS.VTID` will most probably result in duplicates for the sample data that you've posted. You should follow @bluefeet's advice and start debugging your query either by building it up from a small set of tables and watching when duplicates start appearing or by removing tables from the final query, which produces duplicates, and watching when the duplicates are gone (or, perhaps, become fewer), to find the particular join or joins that produce the duplicates.

Comment: Andriy: i m using sql server 2005 so there is no debug option

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Cannot execute script.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger. The Transact-SQL debugger does not support SQL Server 2005 or earlier versions of SQL Server. (SQLEditors)

----------------------------

Comment: getting above error when debug

Answer (score -1):

use `distinct` after select. no need to use at inner join line..

```
 SELECT DISTINCT MID,NAME,SEX,AGE,RFM.TITLE,RFM.NAME 
 FROM MMASTER  
      INNER JOIN AMM ON MMASTER.MID=AMM.MID 
      INNER JOIN PS ON AMM.AMMID=PS.AMMID 
      INNER JOIN PV ON PV.VTID=PS.VTID 
      INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID 
      INNER JOIN PM ON PV.PMID==PM.PMID 
      INNER JOIN SM ON PS.SMID=SM.SMID 
 WHERE PM.PMID='13'
```

if you want all unique data.