# id getting duplicate PV.RFMID

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i use distinct INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688430/how-can-i-use-distinct-inner-join-rfm-on-rfm-rfmid-pv-rfmid)

```
Table MMASTER
   MID col1
   1   abc
   2   xyx
   3   pqr

   Table AMM
   AMMID MID col1 col2
   1     1   bnb  mfk
   2     1   def  rwr
   3     2   re   wrwr

   Table PS
   UID VTID AMMID SMID col1 col2 
   1   1    1     1    rkk  jdj
   2   2    3     3    kdf  lfl
   6   2    2     4    rgr  rtr

   Table PV
   VTID PMID RFMID
   1    2   1
   2    2   3
   7    2   2

   Table RFM
   RFMID title name
   1     mr   john
   2     mr   jack
   3     mr   jim

   Table PM
   PMID col1 col2
   1   df  ere
   2   rwe rwer
   3   rwr fwr

   Table SM
   SMID MMID col1 col2
   1    1    fdf  efe
   2    1    ddf  dfdf
   3    2    df   ef
```

I get result like this after fire above query

```
 PMID title name  PV.RFMID
 2     mr.   jim  3
 2     mr.   jim  3
 2     mr.   jim  3

***BUT RESULT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS***
PMID title name  PV.RFMID
 2     mr.   john   1
 2     mr.   jim    3
 2     mr.   jack   2
```

In my query `PV.RFMID` getting duplicate value when join with `RFM` and due to that title and name getting duplicate

Comment: That's because you filter by `WHERE PM.PMID='2'`, and in PM table got three values with  `PM.PMID='2'`. There you got three joins, that result in your three outputs

Comment: John, what is your question? Also, why do you name your tables AMM, PV, PS etc? It is impossible to find any sense in this names though in queries you can use aliases.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your desired Output:

```
select pm.pmid, rfm.title, rfm.name, pv.rfmid from PM as PM
inner join PV on pm.pmid = pv.pmid
inner join RFM as rfm on pv.rfmid = rfm.rfmid
WHERE PM.PMID='2'
```

**EDIT**

Considering that you *need* to `Join` all `tables`, it's something tricky.
I mean, checking `RFMtable`, you can see the `RFMId`, related to `PV table`, and see that the `VTID` has a 7 value.. which is not related to anything ! So, if you need to `join` all `tables`, you won't get that result

Comment: ya i know above query give me desired output but have to join 7 tables not 2

Comment: do you *really* need to join the 6 tables? Ok, then, let me edit..

Comment: This is not a answer i dont think that this is impossible using 6 table join

Comment: If you related the tables by an Id, you got a problem - you got a VTID = 7, that is not related to anything. So, joining by id's between tables won't work (you'll miss "jack")

Comment: harcode data on select, or correct your db data

Comment: This is not possible to give hardcode data or correct ur db data

Comment: well, it's not possible to invent joins deliberately. Your data probably is incorrect - you missing a VTID = 7 in your PS table

Comment: the data is temporary given not real

Answer (score -2):

I Am assuming that table "PM" is your transaction table where one "PMID" can have multiple Entries, thus Adding a Distinct Clause Before your Query will Get you the Desired Out Put.

Try This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PM.PMID,RFM.TITLE,RFM.NAME ,PV.RFMID FROM MMASTER 
INNER JOIN AMM ON MMASTER.MID=AMM.MID
INNER JOIN PS ON AMM.AMMID=PS.AMMID
INNER JOIN PV ON PV.VTID=PS.VTID
INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID
INNER JOIN PM ON PV.PMID=PM.PMID
INNER JOIN SM ON PS.SMID=SM.SMID
WHERE PM.PMID='2'
```