# Get data from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Medical_Master**

```
       MedicalID MedicalName
       1(pk)     abc
       2         xyx
       3         pqr
```

**Child_Medical_Master**

```
       ChildMID MedicalID Station Name
       1(pk)    1(fk)     bnb     mfk
       2        1         def     rwr
       3        2         re      wrw
```

**Medical_Visit**

```
       VTID  PMID  RFMID age
       1(pk) 2(fk) 1      34
       2     2     3      45
       3     3     1      45
       4     1     2      44
       5     2     2      76
```

**Medical_Study**

```
       UID   VTID  ChildMID SMID   Date  time 
       1(pk) 1(fk) 1        1      kk    jdj
       2     2     3        2      kdf   lfl
       6     3     2        3      rgr   rtr
```

**Doctor_Master**

```
       RFMID  Doctorname
       1(pk)  mr.john
       2      mr.jack
       3      mr.jim
```

**PAtient_Master**

```
       PMID   Firstname LastNAme
       1(pk)  df         ere
       2      rwe        rwer
       3      rwr        fwr
```

**Study_Master**

```
       SMID   MedicalID Description Duration
       1(pk)  1(fk)     fdf         efe
       2      1         ddf         dfdf
       3      2         df          ef
```

I want these columns from tables how should be my correct query?

```
UID,PMID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,AGE,MEDICALNAME,DESCRIPTION,STATION,DATE,DoctorName
```

i have use inner join on 7 tables but not getting correct data.(Doctorname is repeating)

Comment: select distinct RFMID from medical_visit

Comment: Also, you have '==' instead of '=' on the second to last line (though I have no idea of its effect in SQL Server).

Comment: its different bluefeet try to solve the quetion

Comment: Do you only want to return information for the MOST RECENT visit?  Right now you are reporting on ALL visits, which is resulting in the duplication of your data.

Comment: Still can't understand what do you want exactly?

Comment: @John Based on the sample data above, can you show the expected results?

Comment: What is your expected result? And which type of query you need exactly ?

Answer (score 3):

While I do not know exactly what you want for the final result, the query and explanation below might help clear up your issues. Having additional sample data and a sample of the result you want would be helpful but here is my attempt.

I started with a smaller query and worked out to add tables.  First query, this does not get you a lot of data but gets you the `ChildMID`, `MedicalId` and `Station` for your final product. You need the `ChildMID` and `MedicalId` to join more tables. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2a56/2)):

```
SELECT *
FROM Medical_Master mm
INNER JOIN Child_medical_Master cmm
  ON mm.MedicalID = cmm.MedicalId
```

The next table I added the `Medical_Study` table joining on the `ChildMID` that you just got from your previous join.  This will get you the `UID` in your final product ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2a56/7)).

```
SELECT *
FROM Medical_Master mm
INNER JOIN Child_medical_Master cmm
  ON mm.MedicalID = cmm.MedicalId
INNER JOIN Medical_Study ms
  ON cmm.ChildMID = ms.ChildMID
```

In the next join I added the `Study_Master` table.  Here I did something slightly different in that I JOINed the table on two separate fields.  For this query I joined on both the `SMID` field to verify that the Study was correct but I also joined on the `MedicalID` field to make sure that it was using the correct Medical record.  (See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2a56/5)) If you do not join on both fields then you will get one record for each item in the `Medical_Study` but it seems like you want the items with both the Study and Medical that are matching.

```
SELECT *
FROM Medical_Master mm
INNER JOIN Child_medical_Master cmm
  ON mm.MedicalID = cmm.MedicalId
INNER JOIN Medical_Study ms
  ON cmm.ChildMID = ms.ChildMID
INNER JOIN Study_Master sm
  ON ms.SMID = sm.SMID
  AND mm.MedicalID = sm.MedicalID  -- results change if you remove this line
```

The next query is a bit easier, in that you are adding the `Medical_Visit` and the `Patient_Master`. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2a56/14))

```
SELECT *
FROM Medical_Master mm
INNER JOIN Child_medical_Master cmm
  ON mm.MedicalID = cmm.MedicalId
INNER JOIN Medical_Study ms
  ON cmm.ChildMID = ms.ChildMID
INNER JOIN Study_Master sm
  ON ms.SMID = sm.SMID
  AND mm.MedicalID = sm.MedicalID
INNER JOIN Medical_Visit mv
  ON ms.VTID = mv.VTID
INNER JOIN Patient_Master pm
  ON mv.PMID = pm.PMID
```

Final table to add is the `Doctor_Master` which will get you the Doctor's name.  ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2a56/17))  Using the sample data provided before you add the `Doctor_Master` table you have one record but end up with 3 in the end.  This is because the `PMID` has seen all 3 doctor's at some point.

```
SELECT *
FROM Medical_Master mm
INNER JOIN Child_medical_Master cmm
  ON mm.MedicalID = cmm.MedicalId
INNER JOIN Medical_Study ms
  ON cmm.ChildMID = ms.ChildMID
INNER JOIN Study_Master sm
  ON ms.SMID = sm.SMID
  AND mm.MedicalID = sm.MedicalID
INNER JOIN Medical_Visit mv
  ON ms.VTID = mv.VTID
INNER JOIN Patient_Master pm
  ON mv.PMID = pm.PMID
INNER JOIN Doctor_Master dm
  ON mv.RFMID = dm.RFMID
```

Removing all of the fields you do not want the final query is:

```
SELECT ms.UID,
    pm.PMID,
    pm.firstname,
    pm.lastname,
    mv.age,
    mm.medicalname,
    sm.description,
    cmm.station,
    ms.[date],
    dm.doctorname
FROM Medical_Master mm
INNER JOIN Child_medical_Master cmm
    ON mm.MedicalID = cmm.MedicalId
INNER JOIN Medical_Study ms
    ON cmm.ChildMID = ms.ChildMID
INNER JOIN Study_Master sm
    ON ms.SMID = sm.SMID
    AND mm.MedicalID = sm.MedicalID
INNER JOIN Medical_Visit mv
    ON ms.VTID = mv.VTID
INNER JOIN Patient_Master pm
    ON mv.PMID = pm.PMID
INNER JOIN Doctor_Master dm
    ON mv.RFMID = dm.RFMID
```

I think this produces the result that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Njg, just to make this clear the reason why the Doctor's name will be repeating is that they will be visiting more than one patient and each patient will be seen numerous times by that one doctor. So for example for one patient who has been seen 3 times by their doctor they will have 3 "duplicated" lines because the medical_visit table has recorded 3 separate visits.

If you just want to show each patient's details (first name, surname, age, hospital location and doctor) then I would initially remove out the following line:

```
INNER JOIN Medical_Visit ON Medical_Visit.VTID=Medical_Study.VTID
```

Then work around the other tables which rely on that join. Have a look and see what that does, you may need to remove other joins until you find out what is duplicating the information. It may be the case that you need to use a subquery in the join to reduce the duplication coming from a table but first identify what table is causing the duplication 
(I can't use SQLFiddle with your example tables.)

Comment: Good answer. If he wants a Certain Doctor's name to show up in only one row, which Visit should show up on that same row?

Answer (score 1):

Building complex queries may not always be the best solution. Working with joins requires that you keep very good control on where you need left/right/full inner/outer joins to get the required result.

A downside of complex queries, besides it takes time to create, you will never be able to understand at a later moment and maintenance will be a nightmare.

Also, what is the result you want to have? I have realized often that I was expecting only one occurrence of a specific value, but in the real scenario it may in some situations be valid to have multiple identical values. See the comment from Tim Hodges.

IMHO it may be a better option to create a few views where data is joined together on a more simple level and then in the end you have a join from those views. In this scenario you will less likely end up confused and be in better control on how the data should look like.

If you still want to move ahead with your current path, please post the expected result (data, not column names) together with the current query you are using (and its incorrect result, describing why/how it is incorrect), for us to help you further with.

Answer (score 0):

For what i can make of it, i have the following query

```
select  u.UID
      , p.PMID
      , p.FIRSTNAME
      , p.LASTNAME
      , v.AGE
      , m.MEDICALNAME
      , u.DESCRIPTION
      , c.STATION
      , s.DATE
      , a.DoctorName
from    medical_master m
        inner join Child_Medical_Master c
          on  m.MedicalID = c.MedicalID
        inner join Medical_Study s
          on  s.ChildMID = c.ChildMID
        inner join Medical_Visit v
          on  v.VTID = s.VTID
        inner join Doctor_Master a
          on  a.RFMID = v.RFMID
        inner join Patient_Master p
          on  p.PMID = v.PMID
        inner join Study_Master u
          on  u.SMID = s.SMID
```

I get this result

result

u.UID |##| p.PMID |##| p.FIRSTNAME |##| p.LASTNAME |##| v.AGE |##| m.MEDICALNAME |##| u.DESCRIPTION |##| c.STATION |##| s.DATE |##| a.DoctorName

1     |##| 2      |##| rwe         |##| rwer       |##| 34    |##| abc           |##| fdf           |##| bnb       |##| kk     |##| mr.john

6     |##| 3      |##| rwr         |##| fwr        |##| 45    |##| abc           |##| df            |##| def       |##| rgr    |##| mr.john

2     |##| 2      |##| rwe         |##| rwer       |##| 45    |##| xyx           |##| ddf           |##| re        |##| kdf    |##| mr.jim

So, yeah, according to your data you get mr.john 2 times. What i also see is that for a different person you get 2 different age's... that is kinda typical.
Have you done a sanity check on your data?? I think it is going wrong somewhere in there...

Answer (score 0):

Try the one below:

```
    Select MS.UID,
      PM.PMID,
      PM.FIRSTNAME,
      PM.LASTNAME,
      MV.PMID,
      MV.AGE,
      MM.MedicalName,
      SM.Description
      CMM.Station,
      MS.Date,
      DM.Doxtorname                                     
    From Patient_Master PM 
      inner join Medical_Visit MV On PM.PMID = MV.PMID
      inner join Medical_Study MS On MV.UID = MS.UID
      inner join Study_Master SM On SM.SMID = MS.SMID
      inner join Medical_Master MM On MM.MedicalID = SM.MedicalID
      inner join Child_Medical_Master CMM On CMM.MedicalID = MM.MedicalID
      inner join Doctor_Master DM On Dm.RFMID = MV.RFMID
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this query.

```
SELECT    MS.UID, PM.PMID, PM.Firstname, PM.LastNAme, MV.age, 
          MM.MedicalName, SM.Description, 
          CMM.Station, MS.Date, DM.Doctorname
FROM      Child_Medical_Master CMM LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Medical_Master MM ON CMM.MedicalID = MM.MedicalID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          Study_Master SM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          Doctor_Master DM INNER JOIN
          PAtient_Master PM INNER JOIN
          Medical_Visit MV ON PM.PMID = MV.PMID INNER JOIN
          Medical_Study MS ON MV.VTID = MS.VTID ON DM.RFMID = MV.RFMID ON 
          SM.SMID = MS.SMID ON CMM.ChildMID = MS.ChildMID
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86eb3/10).